# Scaling consumers with Axon - Kafka extensions

Tags: apache-kafka, axon

Please help me with guidelines to scale out axon projection using below startegys

- Multi threaded consumer-group
- Consumer service horizontally scaled

Got below setup

1. Kafka topic with two partitions: `KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "axon-events:2:1"`
2. Command service that produces events with configuration:

```
    command-processor:         
    mode: tracking         
    source: kafkaMessageSource
```

3. Query processor with below configurations:

```
    mode: tracking                  
    source: kafkaMessageSource         
    threadCount: 2                 
    initialSegmentCount: 4
```

When I run the query processor I get the followiing warning:

`[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=query-group] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [axon-events-0]`

If I try to run multiple instances of query processor (on two separate ports), only **one** query processor is active at a time.

Comment: I'd firstly recommend to give a go at multi-threading a `TrackingEventProcessor` with a default message source like Axon Server. This is tremendously simpler than with the Kafka extension at the moment.

If you got that going, I'd use the Kafka extension in a _basic_ Kafka configuration. Check the sample on how this is done: https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka/tree/master/kafka-axon-example